# Cannot write XML to file

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing Android app on C# (Xamarin)

I trying to write xml to file

Code of creating XML

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Order"));
            el.SetAttribute("CallConfirm", "1");
            el.SetAttribute("PayMethod", "Безнал");
            el.SetAttribute("QtyPerson", "");
            el.SetAttribute("Type", "2");
            el.SetAttribute("PayStateID", "0");
        el.SetAttribute("Remark", "{Comment}");
            el.SetAttribute("RemarkMoney", "0");
            el.SetAttribute("TimePlan", "");
            el.SetAttribute("Brand", "1");
            el.SetAttribute("DiscountPercent", "0");
            el.SetAttribute("BonusAmount", "0");
            el.SetAttribute("Department", "");

            XmlElement el2 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Customer"));

            el2.SetAttribute("Login", "");
        el2.SetAttribute("FIO", "{FIO}");

            XmlElement el3 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Address"));

        el3.SetAttribute("CityName", "{CityName}");
            el3.SetAttribute("StationName", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("StreetName", "{StreetName}");
        el3.SetAttribute("House", "{HouseName}");
            el3.SetAttribute("Corpus", "");
            el3.SetAttribute("Building", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("Flat", "{FlatName}");
            el3.SetAttribute("Porch", "");
            el3.SetAttribute("Floor", "");
            el3.SetAttribute("DoorCode", "");

            XmlElement el4 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Phone"));

        el4.SetAttribute("Code", "{Code}");
        el4.SetAttribute("Number", "{Phone}");

        XmlElement el5 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Products"));
        XmlElement el6 = (XmlElement)el5.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Product"));

        el6.SetAttribute("Code", "{ProductCode}");
        el6.SetAttribute("Qty", "{QTY}");


            Console.WriteLine ("TUT");
            Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

I try to write it like this, but I don't see it on device.

```
    var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "myFile.xml");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, doc.ToString());
```

How write it to file or maybe something isn't wright in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In row `File.WriteAllText(filePath, doc.ToString());` method `doc.ToString()` returns `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

Instead use `doc.OuterXml` property or `doc.Save(path)` method.

Comment: Where I can see file with xml?

Comment: From your code value of variable `filePath` is "PATH_TO_USERS_FOLDER/CURRENT_USER/Documents/myFile.xml". Like "C:\Users\User\myFile.xml" (In windows). It could be in document folder of current user (In android).

Comment: But I  write for  Android phone, not PC

Comment: You can debug the code?

Comment: Yes.

I debugged code and didn't see in console that my file is writing.

Comment: Try to change "Personal" to "ApplicationData".

Has this error. Could not find a part of the path "/data/data/com.digitalmakers.murakami/files/.config/myFile.xml".

Comment: okay. If I will use  doc.Save(path). How I must write code?

Comment: It simple. `doc.Save(filePath);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97107/discussion-between-eugene-and-alexey-nis).